# How to import a text file, and conduct all the content in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a text file, each line contains a sentence like a=0.5;
I hope to import this text file in mathematica and conduct those sentences.

"ReadLine" or "Import" just introduced the information as plaintext, but I want to conduct the assignments.

```
Import["C:\\Users\\Shellulu\\Desktop\\try1.txt"]
```

I hope I can conduct the information from text in the mathematica platform.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out it by myself.
Use `ToExpression`.